# What is fsa.State method of element Shapes in JointJS library

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jointjs

I'm trying to understand the source code of `Finite State Machine` demo of `Joint Js lib v-2.2`. I got stuck in below `function`

```
function state(x, y, label) {

var cell = new joint.shapes.fsa.State({
    position: { x: x, y: y },
    size: { width: 60, height: 60 },
    attrs: { text : { text: label }}
});
graph.addCell(cell);
return cell;
};
```

In above I tried to get reference of below constructor for `fsa.State` in official doc but not able to find.

```
var cell = new joint.shapes.fsa.State({..});
```

Any hints how does it work.

Ref links:

https://resources.jointjs.com/demos/fsa

https://resources.jointjs.com/demos/joint/demo/fsa/src/fsa.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source code for the demo example of fsa which you can find here - https://resources.jointjs.com/demos/joint/demo/fsa/index.html

You'll see that along with the joinjs library and it's dependencies, there is one more script added

```
<script src="../../plugins/shapes/joint.shapes.fsa.js"></script>
```

If you look at it's source code, this plugin defined the `fsa.State`

```
joint.shapes.basic.Circle.define('fsa.State', {...
```

`fsa.State` is not part of core jointjs library. To use it you have to include this plugin.

Maybe for this reason it's not part of official docs. But you can find the source code on the GitHub https://github.com/clientIO/joint/tree/master/dist  there is a file `joint.shapes.fsa.js`.

Read about defining your own shape https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v2.2/joint.html#dia.Cell.define in the official doc.

Comment: Was it mentioned about GitHub link you posted anywhere in official doc ?

Comment: No. It's my assumption on why it's not mentioned in the official doc.